# How should I store a range of data in a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have to make a database-table about a list of pharmaceutical drugs.

- Column one is the unique identifier field with auto-increment. e.g., "1"
- Column two contains the name of the drug. e.g., "Tramadol"
- Column three contains a list of weights. e.g., "30g , 40g , 50g , 60g"

Using a php while loop and an array, I could echo this data using the following method:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "Drug Name: {$row[1]} Drug Weights: {$row[2]}"
}
```

While this would work, I know it is definitely not the best way. The list of weights would have to be a varchar, rather than actual individual integers. What would be the best way to store and echo a range of information for a single product, as seen in column three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a separate couplings table. Make a table 'weights' containing all possible weights (id, value), and make a 'drugs_to_weights_coupling' with 2 columns (combined primary key): one with the id of the drug, one with the id of the weight.

This is called a 'many-to-many' relation and can be [Googled as such easily.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29)

Comment: @JWH This gives you a clean data model. You can then query it (for output) using a table join and applying a concatenation operator on the weight alternatives inside the sql statement to get a single row per drug.

Comment: @Sherlock Holmes, your eminently pragmatical answers never fail to impress!